# How to Browse files from Mapped Drive in Ubuntu using JFileChooser

Tags: java, ubuntu, jfilechooser

I am having an Application where i am Choosing files by Using JFileChooser . In windows I am able to view and select files from my Mapped network drives.

But in Ubuntu I am not able to see my Mapped Drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unix you don't see the Network directories because you need to use a protocol like Samba to access folder over network.

So if you want to access those folders from FileChooser I suggest you to mount them on your own filesystem, like that you can have access to them from the FileChooser like any regular folder.

[This is a tutorial to mount network drives in Ubuntu](http://www.automaticable.com/2008-01-18/how-to-mount-a-network-drive-in-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I couldn't find a satisfactory answer, but in the end, I created a symbolic link to the mapped drive I was trying to use and put it on a drive I could access. It worked fine.

On Unix, the command for a sym link is

```
ln -s "pathToFolder" "symLinkName"
```